# Structuring multiple components in ext js

Tags: extjs

I have a page where I need to add components in specific order. (render it to a div)

1. Toolbar
2. Form
3. Toolbar
4. Grid

I have studied the doc and I got confused by all those layouts,containers and panels.
I not sure if I should create first some wrapping component(layout,panel) and then insert the components(form,toolbar,grid) or just create a div for each component ?

I would appreciate an example very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application. If you are developing a pure (no html at all) extjs application the layout is handled by containers' layout but, if you are mixing html and extjs component, you can handle the layout with your div elements.

From your question it seems you are using html (and div elements) then you can handle it by your self. However, I recomend you create a container (a panel) with a hbox layout and include your componenets as children and let the panel handle the layout.